# teleport community auth with private github

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, rbac, teleport

We are trying to configure teleport community from gravitational with github connector for authentication. Instead of github.com we want to use our own private installation of github to authenticate against.

I have been unable to find a way how to configure this. Documentation mentions not much in regards to it.

Is it possible at all to configure teleport github connector to point to a private installation of github?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 4):

There's currently no support in Teleport for using a private Github installation rather than github.com. I think that the relevant endpoints in the code are located [here](https://github.com/gravitational/teleport/blob/e06521dfe63d5f198bf03cbf768e01a9110d6875/lib/auth/github.go#L473-L485) - you could always try editing these and building Teleport from source to implement this if you wanted.

Alternatively, please [raise a feature request on Github](https://github.com/gravitational/teleport/issues/new?labels=type%3A+feature+request&template=feature_request.md) and we can add it to the backlog.

Thanks for trying Teleport!